# If there aren't posts, don't show post link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to set previous/next links on both posts & products within wordpress. This is the code that I'm working with:

```
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="prev">
  <span class="nav-label">‹</span>
    <span class="nav-info-wrap">
      <span class="nav-info">
        <?php previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); ?><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
  <span class="nav-label">›</span>
    <span class="nav-info-wrap">
      <span class="nav-info">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); ?>
      </span>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently if there is no previous/next post, the link isn't there, but the container, `<div class="prev"></div>` or `<div class="next"></div>`is still there.

What I'm wanting to do is hide the previous or next link's container, `<div class="prev"></div>` or `<div class="next"></div>` completely if there is no previous or next post, and I'm not sure how to edit what I currently have to get there.

Comment: [Aparently](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_post_link/) `previous_post_link` simply echoes `get_previous_post_link` so you can call that instead and see if the result is an empty link and only echo it if it's not.

Comment: @solarc, this does not work - it completely removes both links altogether.

Answer (score 0):

your code should looks like this

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  // code executed 
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- pagination -->
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="prev">
  <span class="nav-label">‹</span>
    <span class="nav-info-wrap">
      <span class="nav-info">
        <?php previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); ?><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
  <span class="nav-label">›</span>
    <span class="nav-info-wrap">
      <span class="nav-info">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); ?>
      </span>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<!-- No posts found -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help -- I adjusted my question to help better suit the answers. My current code does not show the link if there is no previous/next post, but it's not hiding the container wrapped around the `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link` code, which is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the record while fetching data from database. For example if the you have data base record primary key with auto_increment. you know the first record is always 1 and the last record is the total number of rows. If the primary key matches the criteria you can disable or hide the button.

```
 <?php 
 if ($post = get_post()){
    // $post has false if the post is last or fist.
    }

  ?>
  <div class="navigation">
  <div class="prev">
  <span class="nav-label">‹</span>
    <span class="nav-info-wrap">
      <span class="nav-info">
        <?php previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); ?><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
  <span class="nav-label">›</span>
    <span class="nav-info-wrap">
      <span class="nav-info">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); ?>
      </span>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed up the code a bit, using the snippet here: https://gist.github.com/projoomexperts/e63152d5d8f3264f5a47

```
<div class="navigation">

   <div class="prev"><span class="nav-label">&lsaquo;</span><span class="nav-info-wrap"><span class="nav-info">
    <?php 
        $prevPost = get_previous_post(); 
        $prevThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(150,150) );
        $theTitle = get_the_title();
        $prevLink = get_permalink( $prevPost->ID ); 
    ?>
    <?php if($prevPost){ ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $prevLink; ?>">
            <?php print_r($theTitle); print_r($prevThumbnail); ?>
        </a>
    <?php } ?>
    </span></span></div>


    <div class="next"><span class="nav-label">&rsaquo;</span><span class="nav-info-wrap"><span class="nav-info">
    <?php 
        $nextPost = get_next_post();    
        $nextLink = get_permalink( $nextPost->ID );
    ?>

    <?php if($nextPost) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $nextLink; ?>">
            <?php
            $nextThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(150,150) );
            $theTitle = get_the_title();
            print_r($nextThumbnail); print_r($theTitle); ?>
        </a>
    <?php } ?>
  </span></span></div>

</div>
```

But it creates whitespace between "nav-info" div, so using javascript:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    if( $.trim( $(".prev .nav-info").text())!=='') {
            $(".next .nav-info").parent().parent().hide();
        }
});
jQuery(function($){
    if( $.trim( $(".next .nav-info").text())!=='') {
            $(".prev .nav-info").parent().parent().hide();
        }
});
</script>
```

This resolved all of my issues :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide the posts_link that is empty using display:none; or visibility:hidden. This requires two steps - if we ignore the pagination query $paged routine which I can assume would be in your post page already.

First the jQuery:

```
jQuery( function() {

/* Add class if there are previous and next posts links */
if ( ( jQuery( '#onlist-pagination .alignright' ).length ) && ( jQuery( '#onlist-pagination .alignright a' ).length ) ) {
    jQuery( '#onlist-pagination' ).addClass( 'previous-and-next' );
}

/* Add class if there is just one previous or next post link */
if ( ! ( jQuery( '#onlist-pagination .alignright a' ).length ) || ! ( jQuery( '#onlist-pagination .alignleft a' ).length ) ) {
    jQuery( '#onlist-pagination' ).addClass( 'previous-or-next' );
}

});
```

Then add a nav partial:

```
<div id="onlist-pagination" class="pagination">
<nav><?php 
$prevpost = get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Listings',         $wp_query->max_num_pages );
$nextpost = get_next_posts_link( 'Older Listings', $wp_query->max_num_pages );
echo '<div class="alignleft">' . $prevpost . '</div>'; 
echo '<div class="alignright">' . $nextpost .'</div>'; ?> 
</nav>
</div>
```

And style according to what you don't want to show.

```
#onlist-pagination.pagination div.alignright a,
#onlist-pagination.pagination div.alignleft a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 2;
    font-size: 115%;
    }
#onlist-pagination.pagination.previous-or-next div.alignright,
#onlist-pagination.pagination.previous-or-next div.alignleft,
#onlist-pagination.pagination.previous-and-next.previous-or-next     div.alignleft {
display: none;
}
#onlist-pagination.pagination.previous-or-next.previous-and-next     div.alignright,
#onlist-pagination.pagination.previous-or-next div.alignleft {
display: block;
}
```

I left out the styles for the anchor link itself so you will need some CSS for the left and right divs or just style the anchors using the "hidden" a in     get_next/previous_posts_link

Here is one good link to look at: 
 * get_prev/next_posts_link ($label, $max_page)
 * https://docs.pluginize.com/article/81-cleanly-done-pagination-with-custom-wpquery-objects